# Can not run Excel macro via Python using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I'm trying to run simple Excel macro via Python using xlwings but it doesn't work.

I tried to run Python in JupyterLab. Both code, VBA and Python, are so simple and when I run VBA code in Excel, it works correctly. Also, I tried some simple python code using xlwings like

```py
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('test.xlsm')
sheet = wb.sheets[0]
sheet.range('A1').value = 'test'
```

works correctly.

However, the python code below doesn't work.

```py
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('test.xlsm')
macro = wb.macro('test')
macro()
```

I put this VBA code below on "ThisWorkbook" in ExcelVBA editor.

```
Sub test()
    Range("A1").Value = "This is a test."
End Sub
```

Error message is like this.

```
com_error: "Cannot run the macro 'test.xlsm'!test'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by myself.

I edited the code like this and it works correctly.

```
macro = wb.macro('ThisWorkbook.test')
```